# arcserv agent installation without asking Y or N

Tags: shell-script

I do the ./install  ; it prompts for answers like :
lease enter your choice:[Y|N] (default: N)      y

Do you want to view the installation notes? (y/n):(default: y)    n
How can I automate that so it will read my Y or N answer from another file without me manually entering it each time?
I appreciate any information you can share with me.

Comment: Using the command yes.
[Look this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642711/6051197)

Comment: A fun utility, @RaúlUlisesMartínHernández but it’s not flexible enough to provide variable responses (“y” followed by “n” here)

Comment: If the answer below has solved your problem, please indicate that to the system by clicking the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the installer reads from standard input (as opposed to directly from the tty), you can do:

```
printf "%s\n" "y" "n" | ./install
```

If you really want the response information in a file, you could:

```
printf "%s\n" "y" "n" > response-file
./install < response-file
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want :
y n 2 y n 

would the following be correct:

printf "%s\n" "y" "n" "2" "y" "n" > response-file

./install < response-file

Comment: The formatting is limited in comments, but that looks like the right direction. If you spell out exactly what you need in the Question, then I can update the Answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried the following, still gets stock on the readme filr:

Comment: printf "qy\nn\n2\n/opt/CA\ny\ny\ny\nn\n" | ./install

The \n's are the enter keys